# How to enable sound in iPhone on a local iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am developing a small app and when I run the app in the simulator I hear a sound, but when I run the app in my iPhone I don't hear anything. How to enable this?

in my ViewDidLoad method:

```
 do {
        musicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(string: path)!)
        musicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        musicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
        musicPlayer.play()
    }
    catch let err as NSError {
        print("SOUND ERROR: " + err.debugDescription)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that you **muted your device**. Try to flip the mute switch on the side so that it does not show the red line.

[More information about the buttons and switches on iDevices](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203017)

Comment: Yes, it was. Thanks!